# Sandbox account for Salesforce Marketing Cloud (ExactTarget)

Tags: sandbox

I'm working on an integration between my app (an advertising platform) and Salesforce Marketing Cloud. The purpose of the integration is to push leads that advertisers generate on my app to their Salesforce account (specifically ExactTarget).

I reached out to Salesforce to get a sandbox account and they've got me going through a bunch of agreements/documents and talking about commercials. I'm not an ISV, I'm not in the business of customising and reselling Salesforce products. So I don't understand why I would have to pay for a test account.

Anyone come across a similar situation, and have any suggestions/feedback for me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I worked for a university that had to jump through a bunch of hoops to get a sandbox. I wish I could provide more detail but it seems that they just don't like giving MC Sandboxes out. Even the sandbox we did eventually get was just a production MC org with a limited number of licenses.

Comment: Sounds like they don't actually have sandboxes then.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce does have Marketing Cloud Sandboxes, but they are provided only for partner consultancy companies on special arrangements, not to individual clients or random freelancers.

My current client is actually one of Salesforce Marketing Cloud largest clients in EMEA region with over fifty business units on the account and even they were denied a Sandbox environment, even after months of meetings and escalations.

Apparently there are a lot of 'limitations' with Sandbox environments which is one of the core reasons they do not want to provide these anymore. They are referred to as legacy content. In addition MC sandboxes do not have similar features like Salesforce ones, like sending managed packages over the orgs.

The only actual way is to get a real production environment these days it seems. Though there are rumours that they are planning to re-introduce these next year at some point with a new bunch of certifications, so there is *some* hope.